# Insert into a sequence?

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

Does this SQL make sense?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE order_id_sequence
START WITH 310;

INSERT INTO order_id_sequence VALUES (150);
```

Comment: No. What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve? A sequence is an object that provides you with ascending numbers, not the other way around. I assume this is Oracle?

Comment: thanks was wondering if this was a valid statement

Comment: Are you trying to increment a sequence by 150 as a one-off operation as Bob suggests?

Answer (score 0):

The way you'd usually use a sequence is to select the next sequential value from it:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
```

Or in PL/SQL you can just assign the next value to a variable:

```
DECLARE
  nSeq_value  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  nSeq_value := ORDER_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;

  -- ...etc etc etc...
END;
```

It is possible to alter a sequence to change the minimum value:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE ORDER_ID_SEQUENCE MINVALUE 150;
```

However, if you want to change the 'next' value returned by the sequence the only way to do it is to drop the sequence and recreate it.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Not a validate one. You can try it in a testing env.
In fact, test it by yourself is a good way before asking question here.